# Notation about curves in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, notation, curves

While studying complex analysis a stumbled upon the following notation which is not clear to me what is it's definition (I couldn't even find it in my notes where my professor uses it extensively)

> Given a curve $\gamma$, then we define $R(\gamma)$ as ...

For example I found it while studying Darboux theorem:

> **Theorem (Darboux)**: Let $\gamma: [a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb C$ be a *regular* curve with length $L_\gamma$. Let $f$ be continuous on $R(\gamma)$ then $$\left|\int_\gamma f(z)dz\right| \le L_\gamma \|f\|_\gamma$$ where $\|f\|_\gamma = \sup_\limits{z\,\in\, R(\gamma)}|f(z)|$

or the definition of the winding number:

> **Definition (Winding number):** Let $\gamma$ be a closed curve, $a\in D$ but $a\notin R(\gamma)$, we call the *winding number* of $a$ with respect to $\gamma$ the quantity $$n(\gamma, a) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma\frac{\mathrm dz}{z-a}$$

And there're plenty of other examples but I think that from this two should be clear (not to me unfortunately) what $R(\gamma)$ is.

What I thought is that it could stand for one of this two $$R(\gamma)\equiv \operatorname{Int}(\gamma) \\ R(\gamma)\equiv \overline{\operatorname{Int}}(\gamma)$$ where $\operatorname{Int}(\gamma)$ is the domain upon which $\gamma$ is the boundary (the interior of $\gamma$), but I'm not really sure.

Comment: From what I see, probably my intuitions are not good because for the Darboux theorem $\gamma$ is not a close curve, what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From context, it appears that $R(\gamma)$ is simply the range of the function $\gamma: [a,b] \to \mathbb{C}$.  In other words, it's all the points that lie on the curve itself, not the interior or the closure of the interior.

Comment: That's clear, how was I so blind! Thank you very much for the help, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems pretty clear that $R(\gamma)$ must be the *range* of $\gamma$.  A curve in $\Bbb C$ is not a subset of $\Bbb C$, rather it is a map $\gamma:[a,b]\to\Bbb C$. If the definition of $R(\gamma)$ is $$R(\gamma)=\{\gamma(t):t\in[a,b]\}$$then the examples you give make sense.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! How could I not see it.. thank you so much for the answer! Bot yours and Michael were grate answers but I'm gonna accept Michael's just to give points to the one with less reputation! Nevertheless thank you so much